# Sending to files in c++

Tags: c++, file

I have writen the folowign polymorphic classes.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>

 using namespace std;

 class SaveAndDraw
 {
    public:
      virtual void draw()=0;
      void saveToFile();
 };
 class MakeShape : public SaveAndDraw
 {
   public:
      virtual void draw();

 };

 void SaveAndDraw::saveToFile();
 {
```

How do i save the virtual draw function  to a txt file?

```
 } 

 void MakeShape::draw()
 {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            cout << "*";

        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    SaveAndDraw *creation = new MakeShape;
    creation->draw();
    creation->saveToFile();
    delete creation;
    return 0;
}
```

I do not kow how to save the draw to a file. I know to create the file you must say

```
fstream fout;
fout.open("test.txt");
fout.close();
```

Comment: You can use the normal output (`<<`) operator. Like in `fout << "Hello world\n";`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing to std::cout in your draw function, pass it `fout`.

```
void MakeShape::draw(std::ostream & out)
 {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            out << "*";

        }
        out << endl;
    }
}
```

If you need draw to write to cout, just pass it cout as parameter.
This way, you don't need your saveToFile function anymore.